# Windows Mobile debug on Visual Studio 2008 shows "Operation could not be completed" and "Default output location on device" empty list in Device Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

When I want to debug a Mobile Application with Visual Studio 2008. It shows "Operation could not be completed" and do nothing more.
After a little search, I noticed that the list of "Default output location on device" in Options > Tool > Device tools > Devices > Properties and this, for all the devices.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Operation could not be completed" does not necessary mean that a general empty output setting is the cause. The output location can be set in the project's Device property. Anyway: What happens when you try to debug? Does the emulator start? Then VS will create a socket connection to the device and deploy some remote tools and start the debug listener on the device/emulator... To solve the issue with the empty list you may need to un-install and install the WM6 SDK again.

Comment: @josef : Thank you for your help. In order to answer your question: yes the emulator starts and then VS displays the "Operation could not be completed" message. Anyway, I tried to reinstall WM6 SDK but this did not solve the problem. I then reinstalled VS 2008 (the english version this time) over the old french installation of VS 2008. I can now debug my applications. And you're right, even if the "Default output location on device" list stays empty, I can now debug without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to reinstall VS 2008. Please take a look at my comment below the root question.